# Deserializing Json to java classes using gson library

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, gson

[image]I have these two classes:

```
public class Root {
    public ProfileInfoResult ProfileInfoResult = new ProfileInfoResult();
}

public class ProfileInfoResult {
    public String joiningYear;
}
```

this is my json string which i have to deserialize:

```
{"ProfileInfoResult":{"joiningYear":"2009"}}
```

This is code to deserialize:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString); //responseString= {"ProfileInfoResult":{"joiningYear":"2009"}}
Root resultObj = new Root();
String resStr = obj.toString();
try
{
    resultObj = gson.fromJson(resStr, Root.class);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.i("myyyy", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Java debug says that resultObj cannotbe resolved to a variable.

Comment: Where does the error point to in your code?

Comment: No error in the code but after executing this line 

resultObj = gson.fromJson(resStr, Root.class);

resultObj cannotbe resolved to a variable in variables of debug section.

Comment: This code looks very reasonable, and based on your message your error probably doesn't have to do with JSON or Gson. Can you post the whole class, or confirm that the error happens within a line you posted?

Comment: What is this debug section? Are you using an IDE? Can you post a picture?

Comment: yes i have added the image now. I'm using eclipse.

Comment: No need to create jsonobject because you responseString is already in json format. Just deserialize it using gson.fronJson(responseString, Root.class)

Comment: It seems the JSON parsing is failing somehow. Question though, why is there a ReplaceAll call on the result string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "{\"ProfileInfoResult\":{\"joiningYear\":\"2009\"}}";

    Root root = new Root();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    root = gson.fromJson(str, Root.class);
    TextView b = new TextView(context);
    b.setText(root.ProfileInfoResult.joiningYear);
```

this is working fine.

Comment: is that due to escape sequences missing in my string?

Comment: from where you are getting your string, from any service or it is just hard coded?

Comment: then escape sequences not an issue.

Comment: I don't know why but it automatically start working.

Comment: there was some error warning on this line      Root resultObj = new Root();